# Why is toString.call('my string') different from 'my string'.toString(), or, why is document.toString !== 'asd'.toString?

Tags: javascript

Was reading Underscore.js to see out how its `is[String|Number|...]` methods work, and now I am confused. Underscore does:

```
toString.call(obj) == ['object ' + name + ']';
```

Okay, so, I can do

```
>>> toString.call('my string')
"[object String]"
```

But

```
>>> 'my string'.toString()
"my string"
```

I'm pretty lost here! In the first call I've got:

```
>>> document.toString === toString
true
```

And

```
>>> document.toString === 'asd'.toString
false
```

So, I'm pretty confused. I didn't expect this behavior.

Comment: To clarify, I recognize that `"a string".toString()` should *logically* return `"a string"`. But this seems in conflict with what happens when you do `toString.call("a string")`.

Comment: Why would you think that two different functions would have the same behavior? Just because they're both called `toString` doesn't mean they should do the same thing...

Comment: @Xymostech: I would have guessed that they all inherit from `Object.prototype.toString`. It didn't occur to me that there would be multiple implementations of `toString`. Especially since `String.toString()` is pretty much—despite logical imperative—a "worthless" no-op, if you will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because:

```
document.toString === Object.prototype.toString
```

It implements the most basic version of `toString`, one that's similar to:

```
'[object ' + (typeof this) + ']';
```

This is very different from `String.toString()`, which simply outputs the string itself, i.e.:

```
> String.prototype.toString.call('hello world')
"hello world"
```

Or `Array.toString()` which outputs a comma separated string of values.

```
> Array.prototype.toString.call([1,2,3])
"1,2,3"
```

**Using `.call()`**

To make this work, they basically apply `toString()` on an object by using `.call()`:

```
toString.call(obj)
```

Inside the `toString` method, `this` now refers to `obj`. This would be equivalent:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jack. I was looking for that equivalent you write at the end, and wasn't looking in the right place. Now this makes sense.