# Why does 'abc'.toString() give a different result than toString.call('abc')?

Tags: javascript

Somtehing that's bugging me this morning:

`'abc'.toString()` returns `'abc'`

`toString.call('abc')` returns `'[object String]'`

Why the difference?

Comment: Besides, `'abc'.toString.call('abc')` returns "abc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your primitive string gets boxed into an object when you pass it to [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

The documentation says (emphasis mine):

> Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the
>   method is a function in non-strict mode code, `null` and `undefined` will
>   be replaced with the global object, *and primitive values will be
>   boxed*.

Answer (score 1):

```
toString.call('abc')
```

Currently you use implicitly

```
window.toString.call('abc')
```

which is the same as

```
Object.prototype.toString.call('abc')
```

Try instead

```
String.prototype.toString.call('abc')
```

which is the same as

```
('abc').toString()
```

---

Further proofs for downvoters:

```
true === ( toString === window.toString === Object.prototype.toString )
true === ( 'abc'.toString === String.prototype.toString )
```

Comment: [This related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15182672/1352471) says basically the same as I did.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation of why 'abc'.toString() outputs what it does, which isn't addressed in the accepted answer.  
(I'm going to switch my vote to this answer as soon as SO lets me)